# Evernote API: Can it support JavaScript browser apps?

Tags: evernote

In the [FAQ](http://dev.evernote.com/start/guides/javascript.php) it says this:

“Can I build a browser-based Evernote client using this SDK?”

Probably not; most browsers will disallow sending XMLHTTPRequests across domains, so there’s a very good chance that such an implementation wouldn’t work in most environments.

What does "probably" mean, has anyone got any experience in this regard and has build something browser based?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the same origin policy, you can't send XHR across domains with most browsers.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

It depends on the browser whether it follows that policy but in fact at least major browsers do.  So you basically can't build a browser based Evernote client with Javascript SDK for now.

There is a solution to make HTTP call from another domain called CORS.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Evernote is planning to implement this in the future.